# Configure send Mail Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Can some one explain me how to configure the send mail task is ssis 2012?
I don't where we need to assign our Mail password while configuring.

Answer (score 1):

You specify the password when you set up the SMTP Connection Manager.

The MSDN page on SMTP Connection Manager has all the details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137684(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, The out of the box Send Mail Task in SSIS only supports an SMTP Connection Manager.

Right click in the Connection Managers area and choose **SMTP** as the Type.

[image]

You will now be prompted to Enter the SMTP Mail Server connection details. The minimum required are the SMTP Server's address. The rest default to their default values. Ex: If you don't enter timeout, it defaults to `60000`  = 60 seconds.

[image]

Once you enter the details and press OK, the `ConnectionString` property of the SMTP Connection Manager will be set (see example below)

[image]

It is a good idea / best practice to parameterize this `ConnectionString` property so you don't have to change code if the SMTP server info or connection details change at a later date.

[image]

I keep the SMTPConnectionString at the Project Level (not Package Level) so that it can be re-used across various packages that send emails.

[image]

[image]

If you need advanced control over this component, there is a 3rd party SSIS component provider that has something called [Send Mail Task Plus](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/send-mail-task). That lets you configure an email provider password and such, although I rarely see this need in the enterprise SSIS world.